# VB: howto read a directory tree to txtfile.?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am relly stuck so hope someone can help out.

How do I create a vb program that read a directory tree from i.e disc (C:D:) and out put it to a txt file. ?

Comment: Have you tried anything? This is not a new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    writeDiskTextfile("d:\", "c:\textfile.txt")
End Sub

Sub writeDiskTextfile(path, TextfilePath)
    IO.File.AppendAllText(TextfilePath, "DIR: " & vbTab & path & vbCrLf)
    For Each f1 In IO.Directory.GetFiles(path)
        IO.File.AppendAllText(TextfilePath, "FILE: " & vbTab & f1 & vbCrLf)
    Next
    For Each d1 In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path)
        writeDiskTextfile(d1, TextfilePath)
    Next
End Sub
```